# getClass() of a Generic Method Parameter in a Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

The following Java method fails to compile:

```
<T extends Number> void foo(T t)
{
    Class<? extends T> klass = t.getClass();
}
```

Error received is:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Class<capture#3-of ? extends Number>` to `Class<? extends T>`

Can someone explain why `Class<? extends T>` is invalid, but `Class<? extends Number>` is fine?

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) says:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:

```
Number n = 0;
Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the `T` class' type doesn't extend from `T`. Instead, it extends from `Number`, exactly as you have declared yourself in `<T extends Number>`. Simple as that.

A better question would be:

> Why doesn't the following compile?
>
> ```
> <T extends Number> void foo(T t)
> {
>     Class<T> class1 = t.getClass();
> }
> ```

The answer to that is that the `Object#getClass()` returns `Class<?>` with an unbounded wildcard `?` because the object itself is not directly aware about its generic type which is been expected in an arbitrary method.

Answer (score 5):

It is kind of silly. It would have been better, for most use cases, if `x.getClass()` returns  `Class<? extends X>`, instead of the erased `Class<? extends |X|>`.

The erasure is the cause of loss of information, making your code, apparently safe, fail to compile. `t.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends |T|>`, and `|T| = Number`, so it returns `Class<? extends Number>`.

The erasure (mandated by the language spec) is to maintain theoretical correctness. For example

```
List<String> x = ...;
Class<List> c1 = x.getClass(); // ok
Class<List<String>> c2 = x.getClass(); // error
```

Although c2 seems very reasonable, in Java, there is really no such class for `List<String>`. There is only the class for `List`. So allowing c2 would be, theoretically incorrect.

This formality created lots of problem in real world usages, where programmers can reason that `Class<? extends X>` is safe for their purposes, but have to cope with the erased version.

You can simply define your own `getClass` that returns the un-erased type

```
static public <X> Class<? extends X> getFullClass(X x)
    return (Class<? extends X>)(Class) x.getClass() ;

<T extends Number> void foo(T t)
{
    Class<? extends T> klass = getFullClass(t);
}
```