# Why do Java Generic Method Argument Classes Need to be Cast

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I have a generic method:

```
public <T> boolean saveRow(T row, Class<T> rowClass) {
    Mapper<T> rowMapper = mappingManager.mapper(rowClass);
    rowMapper.save(row);

    return true;
}
```

And I would like to ditch the second parameter since I can infer the `rowClass` from `row.getClass()`.

I've noticed that the only way to make this work is by casting `row.getClass()` to `(Class<T>) row.getClass()`:

```
public <T> boolean saveRow(T row) {
    Mapper<T> rowMapper = mappingManager.mapper((Class<T>) row.getClass());
    rowMapper.save(row);

    return true;
}
```

Why is the cast necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: (BalusC's answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276096/getclass-of-a-generic-method-parameter-in-a-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Class.getClass()` is not aware of the generic.
 `Class<?>` cannot substitute to `Class<T>`.

Look at the signature :

```
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! N00b of me for not checking the signature :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Sometimes the answer is not very far :)